# Do you lose track record of an iOS app when you transfer it to a different owner's account?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I transferred all our apps from a personal account to an account we created related to the company. When I sign in to itunnesconnect I can't access the track record of these apps previous to when I changed ownership (downloads, devices, territories, etc.). I can't find those records either in my original account since the apps are no longer there.

Does anyone know if there is any way to recover that information?

Thanks!!

Comment: This question is more suitable for Apple Support.

Answer (score 0):

See these guidelines https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

It clearly states that

> To initiate an app transfer
>
> Make a record of app information you want to have after the transfer.
>
> Because you won’t be able to view the app information after the transfer, make a catalog report (see Requesting Catalog Reports), note dates the app was available on the store (see Viewing Status History), and save sales and download information (see Viewing Sales and Trends)."